# No instance for (Fractional Int) in expression `pi * r' * r'`

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a very simple area program:

```
type Point = (Int, Int)
data Figure = Rect Point Point | Circ Point Int
area (Rect (x1,y1) (x2,y2)) = (x2 - x1) * (y1 - y2)
area (Circ _ r) = pi * r'^2 where r' = fromIntegral r
```

When I type this manually into `ghci`, it has no errors and works as expected.

However, compiling this program yeilds the following error:

```
No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of `pi'
In the first argument of `(*)', namely `pi'
In the expression: pi * r' ^ 2
In an equation for `area':
    area (Circ _ r)
      = pi * r' ^ 2
      where
          r' = fromIntegral r
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Always use type signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info). In this case, you evidently want the result to be `Double`. Once you make that explicit, the compiler error will become perfectly clear to understand.

---

The reason the error is not clear to understand at the moment is this: from the first clause

```
area (Rect (x1,y1) (x2,y2)) = (x2 - x1) * (y1 - y2)
```

the compiler infers that the result of `area` has the type of `(x2 - x1) * (y1 - y2)`, which is the same type as `xⱼ` and `yⱼ` themselves: `Int`. When the compiler then checks the second clause it finds `fromIntegral'`. That can produce any number type, including `Int`, so no problem here. The multiplication is thus inferred to be integral too. But that means `pi` needs to be `Int` as well, which is obviously nonsense!

With the correct signature,

```
area :: Figure -> Double
```

the compiler will stop right at the first clause, complaining correctly that `Int` doesn't match `Double`. You need another `fromIntegral` here.

Comment: This is a pain in the ass.

Comment: What, that you need `fromIntegral` or that you should write type signatures? Signatures have a number of big benefits, foremostly they make your code easier to understand because you first learn what the functions deals with, and very broadly its purpose, before being heaped with implementation details. — Regarding `fromIntegral`: you wouldn't need it if `Point` didn't use integers for the coordinates. On an integral space, shapes like circles don't really make sense, so it's quite reasonable that you first need to explicitly embed them into a continuous space.

Comment: No no, type signatures are great, what I meant was that in every other language I've used it doesn't need explicit conversion from `Int` to `Double` but it does need explicit conversion the other way around. (Assuming `Num` is like a Double)

Answer (score 5):

## The Problem

The first equation of your function has as return type `Int`, but the second equation has a return type of `Floating a => a`. Now the compiler tries to unify the `a` with `Int`, but `Int` is not an instance of `Floating` (as the compiler tells you), so the compailation fails with a type error.

## Why ghci accepts it.

When you type those lines into ghci, it does not treat the second equation for `area` as extension to the function defintion, but instead overwrites it.
So if you try to use `area` in ghci with a `Rect` it will fail.

Answer (score 5):

You're not getting the error in ghci because you're overwriting your definition of `area` for `Rect`.

If you do it this way, you'll get the error:

```
let area (Rect (x1,y1) (x2,y2)) = (x2 - x1) * (y1 - y2); area (Circ _ r) = pi * r'^2 where r' = fromIntegral r
```

And here's your code (with `-Wall` enabled):

```
Prelude> :set -Wall
Prelude> type Point = (Int, Int)
Prelude> data Figure = Rect Point Point | Circ Point Int
Prelude> let area (Rect (x1,y1) (x2,y2)) = (x2 - x1) * (y1 - y2)

<interactive>:5:5: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘area’: Patterns not matched: Circ _ _
Prelude> let area (Circ _ r) = pi * r'^2 where r' = fromIntegral r

<interactive>:6:5: Warning:
    This binding for ‘area’ shadows the existing binding
      defined at <interactive>:5:5

<interactive>:6:5: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘area’: Patterns not matched: Rect _ _

<interactive>:6:30: Warning:
    Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type ‘Integer’
      (Integral b0) arising from a use of ‘^’ at <interactive>:6:30
      (Num b0) arising from the literal ‘2’ at <interactive>:6:31
    In the second argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘r' ^ 2’
    In the expression: pi * r' ^ 2
    In an equation for ‘area’:
        area (Circ _ r)
          = pi * r' ^ 2
          where
              r' = fromIntegral r
```

In general, it's always a good idea to use `-Wall`.